# Select distinct value from a list in linq to entity

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

There is a table, it is a poco entity generated by entity framework.

```
class Log
{
    int DoneByEmpId;
    string DoneByEmpName
}
```

I am retrieving a list from the data base. I want distinct values based on donebyempid and order by those values empname.

I have tried lot of ways to do it but it is not working

```
var lstLogUsers = (context.Logs.GroupBy(logList => logList.DoneByEmpId).Select(item => item.First())).ToList(); // it gives error
```

this one get all the user.

```
 var lstLogUsers = context.Logs.ToList().OrderBy(logList => logList.DoneByEmpName).Distinct();
```

Can any one suggest how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can I just point out that you probably have a problem with your data model here? I would imagine you should just have `DoneByEmpId` here, and a separate table `Employee` which has `EmpId` and `Name`.

I think this is why you are needing to use `Distinct`/`GroupBy` (which doesn't really work for this scenario, as you are finding).

Comment: there are other fields that i have not mentioned here so the data model is correct , can you suggest  a way to achieve this by using linq

Comment: are you sure? can there be different `DoneByEmpName` values for each `DoneByEmpId`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not near a compiler, so i can't test it, but...

Use the other version of `Distinct()`, the one that takes an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` argument, and then use `OrderBy()`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: I didn't actually look at the fields in Log. Chris Ballard is probably right. It does look odd.

Comment: there are lot of other fields that it have and empid and other details are coming from some other database.....